# How to access HashMap values outside run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, hashmap, server-side

I have a static inner class `mainThreadForPlayers` in my server project. Inside the run method, I want to create an object for each client, containing the client's username, socket, and his IP address. Moreover, I want to store this object in a HashMap. My problem is, the values inside the map are only accessible inside the run method. I'd like to access the Map values inside the `sendMessageToInvitedPlayer` function, but the Map is empty inside the function.

Here's my code:

```
public static class mainThreadForPlayers extends Thread {
       DatabaseConnection data = new DatabaseConnection();
       static HashMap<String, Clients> allUsersInfo;
     
       static{
         allUsersInfo = new HashMap<String, Clients>();
       }
       ServerSocket serverSocket;
       boolean accepted = false;
       boolean x = true;
     
       public void run(){
          try{
            
                   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            
                   while(x){
                       Socket player1 = serverSocket.accept();
                       InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) player1.getRemoteSocketAddress();
                       String clientIpAddress = socketAddress.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                       try{
                         Thread.sleep(15000);
                       }catch(Exception e){}
                       String username = data.getLastInserted();
                       Clients client = new Clients(username, player1, clientIpAddress);
                       InsertIntoMap(username, client);

                    }
                  
               }
               catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }

      public static void InsertIntoMap(String username, Clients client){
           
           if(allUsersInfo.containsKey(username)){
                return;
           }else{
                                
                                allUsersInfo.put(username, client);}
                                for (String name: allUsersInfo.keySet()) {
                                String key = name;
                                String value = allUsersInfo.get(name).toString();
                                System.out.println(key + " " + value);
             }
        
    }

      public void sendMessageToInvitedPlayer(String from_user, String to_user) throws IOException{
 
              if(allUsersInfo.isEmpty()){
                  System.out.println("Hello from server empty");
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("Hello from server NOT empty");

              }
          
           }  
        
    
}
```

Comment: Find the proper scope for the `Map`, or provide methods that do the work of inserting/reading the entries on the `Map` instance. But why do you use inner classes at all?

Comment: @tquadrat I used an inner class because in my main class I manage the server's GUI and I extend Application. I tried creating functions that get the HashMap values from inside the run method but nothing seems to work and I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store this object in a HashMap. My problem is, the values inside the map are only accessible inside the run method. I'd like to access the Map values inside the sendMessageToInvitedPlayer function, but the Map is empty inside the function.

The problem is not that it is a different function, the problem is that it is a different *thread*.  Whenever you are sharing information between 2 threads you need to worry about memory synchronization and locking.  Threads keep information in local memory for performance reasons so synchronizing the local copy of the `HashMap` with the central JVM memory is required – both when reading and when updating the `Map`.  Also, when you are updating a `Map` (or any shared object) you need to worry that you don't get a copy of the memory in the middle of an update which can result in all sorts of problems.  For this reason you need appropriate locking.

`HashMap` is not a synchronized class so updates made by thread executing the `run()` method won't necessarily be seen by another thread calling `sendMessageToInvitedPlayer(...)`.  You can use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which is a reentrant class designed to share information between multiple threads.

More generally, sharing information between threads can be very complex and shouldn't be done lightly.  here's a tutorial about [sharing data between threads in Java](https://medium.com/@jgwest/concurrency-pattern-keep-your-java-objects-safe-from-multithreaded-meddlers-1065bbd2a27d).